# Python stub-files and doxygen

Tags: python, doxygen, stub

Can you simply generate .html via doxygen using documentation in stub-files?

`main.py`

```
    def run_kpi_coverage_on_projects(self):
        for project in [a for a in self.projectList if a not in self.complications]:
            self.jsonValues.run_kpi_coverage(project)
```

`main.pyi`

```
    def run_kpi_coverage_on_projects(self) -> None:
        """
        @summary <br/>
        Method which iterates through all projects and triggers deeper methods. <br/>
        Method calculates all KPIs, communicates with IMS and reads source data.
        """
        ...
```

Generated .html does not cover the `.pyi` files. Can you somehow force it?
[image: Not that one I want]

Comment: Wgich version of doxygen are you using? Which file(s) do you want to feed to doxygen?

Comment: doxygen 1.9.8 but I can update if needed.

Comment: No need for update 1.9.8 is currently the last released version. More important is: Which file(s) do you want to feed to doxygen? Best is to provide the settings you used that are different from  the default settings i.e. the output of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`

Comment: Once I get home from the office I will post it.